# Retrieve records based on preference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with sample data below.

```
PatId        NetType
 100           In
 100           Out
 100           NA
 101           Out
 101           NA
 102           NA
 103           In
```

When there are multiple netTypeid for same patient return only top one prioritized by( In,Out,NA) as order. What i am trying to do when there are In/Out/NA available for a patid then should return back only In, when there is Out/NA available for a patid then it should return back only In.If no duplicate just return back as is. Output for above scenario should be

```
PatId        NetType
 100           In 
 101           Out
 102           NA
 103           In
```

Comment: Please post some code showing what you've tried and the table schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()` to order your table by `NetType`

```
select
    PatId, NetType
from (
    select
        PatId, NetType
        , row_number() over (partition by PatId order by case NetType when 'In' then 1 when 'Out' then 2 else 3 end) rn
    from
        myTable 
) t
where
    rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to uzi

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (PatId int, NetType varchar(20));
insert into @t values 
       (100, 'In')
     , (100, 'Out')
     , (100, 'NA')
     , (101, 'Out')
     , (101, 'NA')
     , (102, 'NA')
     , (103, 'In');

DECLARE @O AS TABLE (ord int primary key, NetType varchar(20));
insert into @O values (1, 'In'), (2, 'Out'), (3, 'NA');

select tt.PatId, tt.NetType 
from ( select t.* 
            , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PatId order by o.ord) as rn
         from @t t 
         join @O o 
           on t.NetType = o.NetType
     ) tt 
where tt.rn = 1;
```